# Flutter - Vertical Divider and Horizontal Divider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In Flutter, is there an option to draw a vertical lines between components as in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Not as far as I know. However, it is quite simple to create one — if you look at the source for [Flutter's Divider](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/divider.dart) you'll see that it is simply a `SizedBox` with a single (bottom) border. You could do the same but with dimensions switched.

---

**Update** (Oct 4, 2018): a `VerticalDivider` implementation has been [merged in](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/22641) by the Flutter team. Check out the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VerticalDivider-class.html) but it's very simple to use — simply put it between two other items in a row.

**Note**: If you are using `VerticalDivider` as separator in `Row` widget  then wrap `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight` , `Container` or `SizedBox` else `VerticalDivider` will not show up. For `Container` and `SizedBox` widget you need define `height`.

Comment: Sorry didn't get a chance to write an example, but I assume you've figured it out by now. I've made a feature request for this [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15926).

Comment: I've tried to use VerticalDivider as separator for in Row widget and... I don't see it! :(

Comment: @AleksTi that might be worth a new question, but make sure that something in the row actually has some height and set the row's crossAxisAlignment to stretch.

Comment: The `Divider` and `VerticalDivider` are such disappointing widgets... Why not have one widget for both, just switching the direction? It could even encompass diagonal or arbitrary direction dividers...

Comment: Documentation says "Vertical dividers can be used in horizontally scrolling lists, such as a ListView". Ive tried to use it in a Row and it doesnt show up. Useless widget :/

Comment: @kashlo Can you check what your `crossAxisAlignment` is set to? If it's set to `CrossAxisAlignment.center` (which is the default), then your dividers will have height of zero and therefore won't be shown. It's a little unintuitive but makes sense from a layout perspective. Try setting `crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`, although be aware that you might have to wrap the rest of the elements in a Center.

Comment: @kashlo its really weird, because you need to wrap your Row widget with an IntrinsicHeight widget for no apparent reason. what a silly design choice.

Comment: Wrapping whole row to IntrinsicHeight is very annoying, it should show up by default without expecting to change anything else.

Answer (score 89):

#### Vertical divider:

- **As a direct child:**

  ```dart
  VerticalDivider(
    color: Colors.black,
    thickness: 2,
  )
  ```
- **In a `Row`:**

  [image]

  ```dart
  IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Text('Hello'),
        VerticalDivider(
          color: Colors.black,
          thickness: 2,
        ),
        Text('World'),
      ],
    ),
  )
  ```

---

#### Horizontal divider:

- **As a direct child:**

  ```dart
  Divider(
    color: Colors.black,
    thickness: 2,
  )
  ```
- **In a `Column`:**

  [image]

  ```dart
  IntrinsicWidth(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('Hello'),
        Divider(
          color: Colors.black,
          thickness: 2,
        ),
        Text('World'),
      ],
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: **Important:** Remember wrap **Column/Row** widgets inside a **IntrinsicWidth/IntrinsicHeight** widget to display the **Divider** that you want.

Comment: Important also: This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible. (As mentioned in the documentation)

Answer (score 73):

As of 10 days ago, flutter [has merged](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/22641) a `VerticalDivider` implementation. It will be available in the default channel very soon, but for now you have to switch to the dev channel to use it: `flutter channel dev`.

Here is a example of how to use it:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
    child: new Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Foo'),
    VerticalDivider(),
    Text('Bar'),
    VerticalDivider(),
    Text('Baz'),
  ],
))
```

Comment: Using IntrinsicHeight widget I get this suggestion "Creates a widget that sizes its child to the child's intrinsic height. This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible."

Answer (score 27):

Try to wrap it inside the `Container` with some height as

```
Container(height: 80, child: VerticalDivider(color: Colors.red)),
```

Answer (score 24):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class VerticalDivider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 30.0,
      width: 1.0,
      color: Colors.white30,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this approach will only work if the divider is placed between other elements. It will occupy all available area in the row if it is the only element in it.

Answer (score 13):

Tried with `VerticalDivider()` but cannot get any divider. I Solved it with

```
 Container(color: Colors.black45, height: 50, width: 2,),
```

Comment: The same thing. I added VerticalDivider as child for Row widget and I didn't see it.

Comment: This works if your VerticalDivider is not showing. Note: I used a SizedBox instead of a Container.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a vertical divider with a thickness of 1.

```
          VerticalDivider(
            thickness: 1,
            color: Color(0xFFF6F4F4),
          ),
```

And if you can't see the vertical divider wrap the row with a **IntrinsicHeight** widget.

Answer (score 8):

Just wrap your Row in IntrinsicHeight widget and you should get the desired result:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Name'),
    VerticalDivider(),
    Text('Contact'),
  ],
))
```

Answer (score 3):

As @rwynnchristian suggested, this seems to be the simplest solution IMO. Just leaving the code here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class VerticalDivider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => RotatedBox(
    quarterTurns: 1,
    child: Divider(),
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use VerticalDivider now

Comment: This does not work anymore

Answer (score 3):

add this method anywhere.

```
  _verticalDivider() => BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        right: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor,
          width: 0.5,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

now wrap your content in container

```
Container(
  decoration: _verticalDivider(),
  child: //your widget code
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Container for divider is easy**, wrap your row in IntrinsicHeight()

[image]

```
          IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Admissions',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34),
                    ),
                    Container(width: 1, color: Colors.black), // This is divider
                    Text('another text'),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `VerticalDivider()` widget with the `IntrinsicHeight` widget. Otherwise, the vertical divider will not show up. And to gain some padding over the top and bottom you can add indent.

```
IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: VerticalDivider(
                        thickness: 0.8,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        "Random Text",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: AppColor.darkHintTextColor,),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

Comment: why do we need IntrisicHeight always to show VerticalDivider?

Answer (score 1):

I guess i found a more robust solution when dealing with this problem;[image]

```
IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BoxRadius.circular(),color: Colors.gray),
                          height: 5,
                          margin: CustomPaddings.horizontal(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "TEST",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .subtitle1!
                            .copyWith(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BoxRadius.circular(),color: Colors.gray),
                          height: 5,
                          margin: CustomPaddings.horizontal(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RotatedBox in combination with a divider to get it vertical, RotatedBox is a widget of flutter that automatically rotates it's child based on the quarterTurn property you have to specify.  Head over to here for a detailed explanation https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Container as a divider, with the desired with 'thickness if for horizontal divider' height 'thickness if for vertical divider'

```
Container(
           color: Colors.blue,
           width: 7,
           height: 77,
           ),
```

This class is relatively **expensive**. Avoid using it where possible. (As mentioned in the documentation) –
Omar Fayad