# How to make a row having icon and text tappable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 2 questions related :

1. I have nested function `BuildButtonColumn` which takes an icon
   and text below it and I want to make it tappable. I know
   `GestureDetector` has `onTap` property, but how do I use that in the
   function `BuildButtonColumn` ?

   ```
   Column buildButtonColumn(IconData icon, String label) {
     Color color = Theme
         .of(context)
         .primaryColor;

     return Column(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
         ),
         Icon(icon, color: color),
         Container(
           margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
           child: Text(
               label,
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 14.0,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                 color: Colors.black,
               )
           ),
         )
       ],
     );
   }
   Widget buttonSection = Container(
     child: Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
       children: <Widget>[
         buildButtonColumn(Icons.message, 'Message'),
         buildButtonColumn(Icons.videocam, 'Request Video')
       ],
     ),
   );
   ```

I took button layout reference from [here](https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/).

And this is the UI wherein I need to open specific screen on each icon or text tap.

[image]

2. I also want to show a vertical divider between them. I followed
   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388281/flutter-vertical-divider) SO post, but it didn't work out for me or I might have
   missed something there to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `return Column` you can write:

```
return GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){ ... },
    child: Column(),
)
```

Regarding divider - `VerticalDivider()` is totally fine for me

```
Widget buttonSection = Container(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      buildButtonColumn(Icons.message, 'Message'),
      VerticalDivider(color: Colors.black,),
      buildButtonColumn(Icons.videocam, 'Request Video')
    ],
  ),
);
```

It has to work

Comment: if I try to `return GestureDetector`, its giving me an error `return type GestureDetector isn't a column, as defined by BuildButtonColumn`. Also, I would need to open 2 different screens after tapping on `Message` and `Video` respectively, how do I achieve that ? Also for divider, do I have to import any package that has `VerticalDivider()` method ? or I need to create a method for it? and what goes into that ? Sorry, but given solution is not clear to me. It would be great if you could elaborate both. @Andrey

Comment: When you tried GestureDetector - did you change `Column buildButtonColumn` to `GestureDetector buildButtonColumn` or better `Widget buildButtonColumn`?

Comment: Yes @Andrey, I first tried with `GestureDetector` but decided to go with more generic `Widget` and the reason I was confused was since I wanted to have 2 different `tap` for two buttons which has now been resolved.  Regarding `VerticalDivider()`, is that a built-in method ? because I tried to implement that but didn't work out yet.

Comment: So, you solved problem and GestureDetector and VerticalDivider works fine?

Comment: Yes, regarding `VerticalDivider()`, this worked for me : Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 30.0,
      width: 1.0,
      color: Colors.white30,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
    );
  } and then just called the class per your suggestion.