# How to add a vertical bar before first line of text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, text

I am new to flutter and I want to add a vertical line before first line of text like the following:

[image]

How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `|` symbol along with font weight set to bold {Use `rich text` if you want different stylings}

Comment: Maybe this can help : `VerticalDivider()` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388281/flutter-vertical-divider/52804106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the indentation on the latter lines, you’ll need to use a Row. I used the vertical bar key `|` as Aayush suggested. VerticalDivider is more suitable if you need to control the thickness, but I just gave the Text extra weight.

```dart
child: Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: const [
    Text('| ',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
    Flexible(
      child: Text("I'm having some trouble with your zip code. Your zip code should be 5 digits. For example, 10003, 90210, etc. Please enter a valid zip code."),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Here’s how that looks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yup! This is exactly what I was trying to say ! Also after wrapping this with richtext, one can apply the desired style to the bar :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**According to your UI**

```
 Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    ///depend on font Size
                    height: 16,
                    width: 1.5,
                    color: Colors.blue.shade400,

                    /// <= margin  text container
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6, left: 8),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "I'm having some trouble with your zip code. Your zip code should be 5 digits. For example, 10003, 90210, etc. Please enter a valid zip code.",
                        maxLines: null,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

**Simple way of left border**

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  border: Border(
                    left: BorderSide(
                      width: 4,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "I'm having some trouble with your zip code. Your zip code should be 5 digits. For example, 10003, 90210, etc. Please enter a valid zip code.",
                  maxLines: null,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```